# What is the easiest way to convert an unsigned long to BigInteger

Tags: java

Java has no support for unsigned longs, but if you treat the longs as unsigned and do multiplication, it works just fine. For comparison, you can use `Long.compareUnsigned()`.

When I do

```
long v = Long.MAX_VALUE; //2^63
v = v+1;
BigInteger vv = BigInteger.valueOf(v);
System.out.println(vv);//this prints -1
```

THe only way I found was doing

```
long v = Long.MAX_VALUE; //2^63
v = v+1;
BigInteger vv = new BigInteger(Long.toUnsignedString(v));
System.out.println(vv);//this prints 2^63+1
```

Comment: The first code example prints `-9223372036854775808` when I execute it, not `-1`. However, there's a sign in the result.

Comment: If you want to avoid overflow, then convert the `long` to a `BigInteger` before you do the addition; do the addition with the `BigInteger` instead of with the `long`.

Comment: btw `Long.MAX_VALUE` is `2^63 - 1` and `Long.MAX_VALUE + 1` gives `Long.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your knowledge of how 2's complement arithmetic works, you can do this:

```
private final BigInteger TWO_POW_64 = BigInteger.TWO.pow(64);
...

Long v = <some negative value to be treated as unsigned>;
BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(v).mod(TWO_POW_64);
```

Comment: `new BigInteger(Long.toUnsignedString(v));` is easier.

Comment: @saka1029deleted yes, it's easier, but maybe not as performant because it has to create a string and then parse it back, whereas this answer uses just a simple calculation.

Comment: If performance matters, it's funny to calculate 2^64 every time.

Comment: @saka1029deleted true. It can be created as a constant. Edited.